# KVM virtual machine: memory usage grows spontanuesly

Tags: virtualbox, 20.04, virtualization, ram, kvm-virtualization

I'm using a virtual machine created by virt-manager on my PC with Ubuntu 20.
In this machine runs also Ubuntu 20 which I migrated from a VirtualBox VM (converting the virtual disk to qcow2; + uninstall GuestAdditions) because the performance is better in KVM (in VirtualBox the sound stuttered, etc.)

Now to my problem: after a while surfing the internet in the VM the memory got to 100% without reason and the system froze. After a restart of the VM everything seemed normal and I continued my work; but after some time it happened again. The System-Monitor did not show any process with a huge memory consumption and the RAM got fuller and fuller (I increased the swap so the system did not froze so fast this time)

I would be glad if anyone can give me a hint to solve this problem.

Comment: If you size a VM to e.g. 4G it will from the host POV still only use what it touches, so it will start small. Over time the guest will use more and more things for caches er similar. Due to that the "guest grows" from the Hosts POV. If that explains your case (the most likely explanation) then it comes down to size your guest correctly and if you want consider setting up and controlling virtio-balloon.

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt I do not think it is caused from normal memory consumption by the system, because it grows rapidly (more than 8 GB in less than two minutes).

Comment: Yeah ok, I agree that sounds too fast  - almost like something doing a low prio background scan of all memory pages. You might take a look with `smem` or `proc/meminfo` what in the guest actually consumes the memory (if anything is listed)

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that I found was to create a new VM with a fresh installation of Ubuntu and to move all data and settings manually.

Only two things that caused the issue comes to my mind:

- some residues from the VirtualBox Guest Additions caused the problem
- the migrated VM was installed with UEFI the and in new VM I use BIOS so it might be that there was a bug with the emulated UEFI